# How mature is Visual Studio 2010 database edition schema compare feature?

Tags: database-design

We are considering to use Visual Studio 2010 database edition's schema compare feature to generate the incremental change script for each change developer makes to the DB model. Could you please share your experience with it? Is it mature enought with data models growing in complexity and size?

p.s.: SQLCompare from RedGate is around for longer, however $600/dev looks way too expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use both tools (DBPro and Red-Gate) in our company. We've used both for a long time. This is not exactly an apples to apples comparison because DBPro does some things Red-Gate cannot. For example, DBPro can compare DBPro project files and databases. Obviously Red-Gate cannot.

Both tools will do the job for you. I like Red-Gate better. It's cleaner and generates more efficient T-SQL code in many cases. But I use both tools heavily and I have confidence in both tools. I'm confident both tools will handle your largest and most complex schema's.

I have to say though that I am not encouraged by Microsoft neglect of DBPro recently. I don't believe it is still a high priority for them. In fact, I'm pretty certain it isn't. But they are still maintaining it and adding some new features.